# Bootstrap multiselect Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-multiselect

I create test application with bootstrap-multiselect. But I can't open dropdown combobox. In page I get exeption:Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function) About:96jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-2.1.1.js:3073jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-2.1.1.js:3185jQuery.extend.ready jquery-2.1.1.js:3391completed. I can't decided this error

```
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

HTML code: 
         
                        
                        
                            Gender
                            
                                
                                    Male
                                    Female
                                    Other
                                Male  Male

Female

Other

The gender is required
                            
                        
                        
                            Browser
                            
                                
                                    Google Chrome
                                    Firefox
                                    IE
                                    Safari
                                    Opera
                                    Other
                                None selected

Google Chrome

Firefox

IE

Safari

Opera

Other

Please choose 2-3 browsers you use for developing
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                Validate

Javascript:
        
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.multiselect').multiselect();
            });

Comment: Problem was in <link> and <script> ordering

Comment: @zrabzdn Hey Please Post your Answer, If you have Solved it.
Thanks....!!!

Comment: @HP's 411. Hi, I change ordering of link and script. First of all I added styles links and after that <script> links

Comment: @zrabzdn : Thanks for Your reply. Let me try, does it solve my Problem or not.